# Trigger eventListener based on selecting of list item from dropdown list

Tags: javascript

[image]

As shown in the image above there is a dropdown list. When I select one of the `<li>` from the list the search box is filled with the content of the `<li>` which is what I would like it to do but the Google Maps marks are not shown in the map unless I hit enter.

I would like for the eventListener to trigger based on selecting the item from the dropdown list or once the search box is filled with the content in this case `Jackson Avenue, New York, USA`.

```
this._searchEl.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      let predictions = event.target.predictions;

      this.displayPlacesOnMap(predictions);
    });
```

I'm using on `change` but it doesn't achieve what I want.

```
  // Attach handler for the autocomplete search box. This updates the map
    // position and re-sorts locations around that position.
    this._searchEl.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
      if(event.target.value) {
        this._service.getPlacePredictions({
           input: event.target.value,
           offset: 3,
           types: ['geocode'],
           componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' },
           bounds: this._map.getBounds()
        }, (predictions) => {

          if(predictions) {

            let results = predictions.map(e => [e['description']]);

            this._missPlete.options = results;
            event.target.predictions = predictions;

          }
        });
      }
```

Above is the library used to display the dropdown list. https://github.com/devowhippit/miss-plete-js/blob/master/src/MissPlete.js

If I hit `enter` after the search box is filled with the content from the list item the map marks are shown. But what is the event to use when the `<li>` is selected?

```
 displayPlacesOnMap(mapItems) {
     if(mapItems) {
       mapItems.forEach(place => {
         let request = {
            placeId: place.place_id,
            fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry']
         }

         const officeMap = this;

         this._placeService.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              officeMap._mapPosition = place.geometry.location;
              officeMap._map.panTo(officeMap._mapPosition);
              officeMap.sortByDistance().clearLocations().updateUrl().updateList()
                  .updateUrl();
              $(officeMap._searchEl).blur();
            }
         })
       })
     }
   };
```

Comment: is <li> created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an event listener like this? Would this work for you.

```js
function doASearch() {
  console.log('searching');
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('.searchable')){
    document.querySelector('#search').value = e.target.innerText;
    doASearch();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='searchable'>Test</li>
  <li>Not Searchable</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: Steven, you can check the input on the click to see if 'checked'